# Google App Engine: Using custom entry point with Python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm starting to learn Google App Engine, and have written a basic main.py file with a Flask application, which works fine.  Here's the first few lines of code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def root():
    return jsonify({'status': "Success!"}), 200
```

I wanted to change the name of the script, so I renamed it 'test-app.py' and added this line to app.yaml:

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: test-app:app
```

Then re-run gcloud app deploy.  The deployment is successful, but app returns 500 with this in the logs:

```
2021-05-09 22:23:40 default[20210509t222122]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-05-09 22:23:41 default[20210509t222122]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: test-app:app: not found
```

I also tried these from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup):

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT test-app:app
entrypoint: uwsgi --http :$PORT --wsgi-file test-app.py --callable application
```

In both cases, logs show "/bin/sh: 1: exec: (gunicorn|uwsgi): not found"

In Lambda, the Entry point is set via the handler option, which is by default a function called lambda_handler() in a file called lambda_function.  It would appear App Engine uses "app" inside "main.py", but what's the proper syntax for changing this?

Comment: why are you changing the name?  you really shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app is not working most probably because you forgot to add gunicorn to your dependencies. 
In your `requirements.txt` file add the following line (you can change the version):

```
gunicorn==19.3.0
```

Then in `app.yaml` add the following line:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT test_app:app
```

This should be enough for the default app to run as expected. 
However if you want more complicated configuration for your server you can create a `guniconrn.conf.py` and add the your preference to it. In that case you have to specify it in your entry point:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT main:app
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer above is mostly correct, but doesn't explain the root cause.  The documentation says gunicorn is the "recommended" web server, but in reality it's the ***default*** web server when web-based apps are deployed.

When deploying a Flask app on App Engine, gunicorn becomes a hidden dependency and assumes the entry point to app() in main.py.  For a custom file/entry point, it does need of course to be set in the YAML file like so:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 2 test_app:app
```

Or, if using uwsgi as the web server rather than gunicorn:

```
entrypoint: uwsgi --http :$PORT --wsgi-file test_app.py --callable app --enable-threads
```

In either case, uwsgi or gunicorn are no longer hidden dependencies, and thus need to be specified in the requirements.txt file.  Personally, I was not familiar with either, since I'd used [Werkzeug](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) or [Apache/mod_wsgi](https://layer77.net/2021/03/22/migrating-from-cgi-to-wsgi-for-python-web-scripts-on-apache/)